# SOLR schema - storing of document Id field. Maximum number of documents in Lucene index

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a couple of questions about Lucene/SOLR index schema

1. Here's my document Id field (UniqueKey) as defined in SOLR schema:

   <field name="Id" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />

I will never perform search by the Id field so does it need to be indexed="true"? And BTW, does it need to be stored="true" (I assume it will be stored anyway so it doesn't matter).

And 2: what is the maximum number of documents that can be stored in single SOLR index? Or, to be more precise: can it hold 5 billion of small documents?

Third question: I need to perform search on a combination of 2 fields: one of type long and one integer. What is the most efficient way of storing and indexing such fields - store and index them separately or pre-compute some hash value based on both of them and search by the hash only? Since I want to have few billions of such documents I need to minimize storage needs while keeping the search efficient.

Thanks
RG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#The_Unique_Key_Field

   > It is not mandatory for a schema to have a uniqueKey field
2. Solr can hold a maximum of [~274 billion](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/fileformats.html#Limitations) Documents. Handling and Search response will depend on the memory. However, if your index size grows and is not maintainable, you can use [Distributed Search](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch).
3. You can combine the fields into a single field as hash and not mark it as stored to reduce the index size. This would speed up the initial searches. Caching should take care of similar searches.

Comment: Is there some rule of thumb about the complexity of the documents and Solr's memory usage?

Comment: Complexity of the Document should not be a problem, but there are no rules for it. Memory usage depends upon the Index size and the cache configuration you are using. Solr will perform the best if the whole index can fit into the memory and it does not need to do a file lookup.

Comment: "Solr can hold unlimited number of Documents" so it currently has no 2.1B document limit?

Comment: yup .. thats correct .. and would be improved in further releases. Have modified the answer. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: this answer points to the right limitations section but interprets it incorrectly.  As recently as Lucene 4.5, a single solr core can hold a maximum 2.1 billion documents with 274 billion unique terms.

The 'unlimited' number of documents refers to a distributed/cloud solr setup with multiple cores/shards.

Comment: @Jayendra Is there any limit on the number of fields we can specify in a schema/document can have?

Comment: FWIW the limit above does not apply to distributed Solr Cloud installations. Presently working with a collection that has 430 billion docs.